# Por quê minha pagina não redimensiona e como fazer ela redimensionar?

Tags: html, css, html5

Em tela cheia fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando coloco em tela menor fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>--</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
                <p id="letreiro">MarceloSantos.com</p>

                <figure id="logo">
                <img src="_img/logo.png" alt="Um programador em seu PC">
                </figure>

                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a  href="#inicio">ÍNICIO</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#portfolio">PORTFÓLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#redes-sociais">REDES SOCIAIS</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>

            <footer>

            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código CSS:

```
body {
}
#letreiro {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: courier, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    padding: 30px;
}
#menu ul {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
#menu ul li {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #696969;
    font-family: impact;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin-left: 80;
    margin-right: 80;
    display: inline-block;  
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Leia esses dois artigos https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/ e aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Comment: A página está redimensionando. Parece que o único problema está no tamanho da fonte do texto que fica no topo, que não acompanha o redimensionamento.

Answer (score 0):

## Estudo

Como o @hugocsl sugeriu: deves usar media queries. Isso, nada mais é do que uma instrução para o navegador carregar diferentes regras CSS, de acordo com a largura do dispositivo acessado ou outras condições.

### Exemplo

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { /* Novas regras, quando atinge 600px */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">Ate cubanos</div>
```

No código acima, a box assume a largura de 50% em telas menores que 600px. Portanto, quando a tela tem largura de 601px pra cima, assume width de 100%.

## Seu caso

Dado o que expliquei, podemos fazer algo parecido com a propriedade font-size, que seria uma solução para você.

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { /* Novo tamnho de fonte, quando atinge 600px */
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1">Ate cubanos</div>
```

Links úteis

- [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp);
- [CodeAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAxbHLgybnY).

Answer (score 0):

Em em de usar `px` para definir o tamanho da fonte, use `vw` (referente ao tamanho do *viewport*). Desta forma, o tamanho da fonte irá acompanhar o tamanho do *viewport*.

```
font-size: 5vw; /* 5% da largura do viewport */
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
#letreiro {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: courier, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    padding: 30px;
}
#menu ul {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
#menu ul li {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #696969;
    font-family: impact;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin-left: 80;
    margin-right: 80;
    display: inline-block;  
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <p id="letreiro">MarceloSantos.com</p>
   <figure id="logo">
      <img src="_img/logo.png" alt="Um programador em seu PC">
   </figure>
   <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
         <li><a  href="#inicio">ÍNICIO</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#portfolio">PORTFÓLIO</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#redes-sociais">REDES SOCIAIS</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

</header>

<footer>
</footer>
```